# Categorical setting for cancellation in direct sums

Tags: ct.category-theory, isomorphism-testing

I am wondering whether some criterion can be put on a category $\mathcal{C}$ with direct sums to ensure that for three objects $X,Y,Z$ one has
$$
X\oplus Y \cong X \oplus Z\Longrightarrow Y\cong Z.
$$
For $\mathcal{C}$ being the category of finitely generated abelian groups this is certainly true, and this is also true for arbitrary abelian groups when $X$ is finitely generated by a theorem of Cohn and Walker. In the case that $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules, where $G$ is a finite group, this property is discussed at length in Richard Swan's paper [Projective modules over binary polyhedral groups](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1983.342.66) J. Reine Angew. Math. 342 (1983), 66–172, MR0703486.

I would expect some *formal* criterion at least to exist, even if it may be relatively hard to check or to apply. Of course, the more useful and easier to apply, the happier I am!

Comment: For finitely-generated abelian groups, or finitely-generated modules over a PID, doesn't this follow directly from the classification thereof? Perhaps the theorem of Cohn and Walker is meant to refer to something else?

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks, you are right! I have modified and corrected the statement.

Comment: I edited in a link to the Swan paper.  Do you have a reference for the theorem of Cohn and Walker?

Comment: I'm more familiar with formal _non_-cancellation arguments like the [Eilenberg swindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Mazur_swindle). Even when everything is "suitably finite", non-cancellation shows up when talking about [stably-free modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stably_free_module) and bundles, for example. OTOH I suppose if everything is free and finitely-generated, then one is talking about Invariant Basis Number rings, among which are all commutative rings. I think cancellation may also hold in an Artinian abelian category?

Comment: You might need to look at Krull-Schmidt categories, they satisfy this property.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks!